# TypeError: ctx.translate is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I'm following a tutorial on using react with html5 canvas. The author is using a class base component and therefore using componentDidMount when a method updateCanvas() has rendered.

I'm using a function based component along with hooks. Therefore I am using useEffect when the methods drawTree, Branch and Leaf rendered.

I am receiving an error message 'TypeError: ctx.translate is not a function' in my browser, but in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-shape-whtqc?file=/src/App.js) I am not receiving any error message but my component is not rendering. Additionally in my code editor .getContext('2D') is grayed out and when i hover over it i get a message 'unresolved function or method'.

[image]

Comment: There are many many errors in your code and just the error you are receiving. Could you please tell what are you trying to do when you call `branch(...state);` since branch function only takes one argument. Also what argument is it supposed to take

Comment: I'm using React to recreate this project https://codepen.io/Paradoks/pen/yxyqZG?editors=1010. I was attempting to use the spread operator rather than doing branch(startLength, angleR, angleL, lengthR, lengthL, leaves)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `.current` key of the `ctx` reference to access it. For example:

```js
function drawTree() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(state.centerX, state.bottom);
  branch(...state);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

should be:

```js
function drawTree() {
  ctx.current.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.current.beginPath();
  ctx.current.translate(state.centerX, state.bottom);
  branch({ ...state }); // Fixed this line too, `branch` is taking an object as its argument.
  ctx.current.stroke();
}
```